# Can I leave ICN airport on an 8-hour layover? Indonesian citizen, US Green Card

Tags: customs-and-immigration, international-travel, transit-visas, south-korea

I'm an Indonesian citizen with a US green card. I'm traveling to Jakarta. I have an 8-hour layover in South Korea. Based on https://visa.go.kr/, I'm pretty certain that I don't need a tourist/transit visa. However, am I allowed to leave the airport?

Comment: The page you link to says you may stay up to 30 days... Did you expect them to restrict you to the airport for that duration? :) :) :)

Comment: You know, my inkling was that I’d be able to leave the airport but I don’t want to guess with immigration matters. I’ve re-read the information on the page so many times — I just need some reassurance 

Answer (score 1):

As your linked site confirms, as an Indonesian passport holder and an individual with US permanent residency, the Republic of Korea allows you to *travel to or transit through Korea without a visa. You will be able to stay for up to 30 days in Korea.*

> **Tourists in transit to Third Countries**
>
> 1. **Eligible Applicants**
>      Citizens of all countries except Syria, Sudan, Iran, Macedonia, Cuba, Republic Of Kosovo, Palestine, Afghanistan, Iraq, Nigeria, Ghana, Yemen.
> 2. **Requirements**
>      Persons who hold a visa (re-entry permit, permanent residency, etc.) to enter the United States, Canada, Australia, or New Zealand (hereinafter referred to as “the four advanced countries”) and
>      ➣ who go to one of the four advanced countries in transit through Korea; or
>      ➣ who stay in one of the four advanced countries and take a direct flight from the country to Korea to go to a country of nationality or a third country.
>
> Please be noted that:
>   ➣ If you are a U.S. visa holder who transit through Korea and Saipan to reach the U.S. as the final destination, you are permitted to enter Korea without a visa. (However, if you depart from the U.S. and enter Korea via Saipan, you are not granted no-visa entry to Korea.)